Не создаёт экземпляр класса CandidateDAO
При попытке инициализировать класс CandidateDAO, возникает ошибка TypeError: CandidateDAO() takes no arguments
Сам код ниже
from blueprints.candidates.dao.candidates_dao import CandidateDAO
# Создаем блюпринт
candidates_blueprint = Blueprint("candidates_blueprint", __name__)
# Создаем DAO
candidates_dao = CandidateDAO("./Work/Big_task/data/candidates.json")

Код класса
class CandidateDAO:
    def init(self, path):
        self.path = path

P.s добавляю print(CandidateDAO), выводит что класс инициализировался успешно <class 'candidates.dao.candidates_dao.CandidateDAO'>

Вы пробовали  заменить  def init(self, path):   на def __init__(self, path):

Добаил. Теперь всё заработало. Спасибо!

Проблема была в определении класса:
class CandidateDAO:
    def init(self, path):
        self.path = path

Надо было написать:
class CandidateDAO:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

